# Read contents of a local file into a variable in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

All I want to do is get all the content from a local file and store it in a variable. How?

`File.read(@icon.full_filename).each {|l| r += l}`

only gives me a part of it. In PHP, I just used `file_get_contents`.

Comment: I feel this is a uniquely Windows problem, because this solution, and the one proposed by zed_0xff work perfectly fine on Mac/Linux. I know that irb turns \r\n to \n when doing File.read... perhaps that's relevant here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answering my own question here... turns out it's a Windows only quirk that happens when reading binary files (in my case a JPEG) that requires an additional flag in the open or File.open function call. I revised it to `open("/path/to/file", 'rb') {|io| a = a + io.read}` and all was fine.

Comment: Unless you're actually concatenating a bunch of files together, I'd just write that as: `data = File.open("file", "rb") {|io| io.read}`

Comment: You sir, deserve a medal. I lost hours trying to figure out why my PDF attachments were unreadable when sent from a Windows server until I stumbled upon this answer.

Answer (score 182):

```
data = File.read("/path/to/file")
```

Comment: I thought that, but that gives me a string of length 52. The actual file size when I go File.size("/path/to/file") is 1676.

Comment: Doesn't that leave the file open?

Comment: I like this one! It would be nice to know how to keep the headers from file content type

Comment: This is useful to read without use of a block, allowing contents to be easily parsed and set to variables available to other blocks without the need for creating a class.

Comment: To address @TomRossi's question -- no, this does not leave the file open. Calling read on the File class opens, reads, and closes the file. However, calling read on an instance of file (which had to be opened first) does not close it. The method being called here is https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-c-read as opposed to https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-i-read

Answer (score 19):

I think you should consider using `IO.binread("/path/to/file")` if you have a recent ruby interpreter (i.e. >= 1.9.2)

You could find `IO` class documentation here http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html

Comment: This is shorter and closes the file for you.