# Rails 3 ActionMailer corrupts attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I'm using Rails 3.2.13 and have been following along with the ActionMailer guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-with-attachments), but I'm having difficulty with sending email attachments.

After execution the email sends properly but the attachment is always corrupted. In particular, I see the rendered email and the correct filename for the attachment but as a 1KB file that can't be opened. I've seen similar issues around stack overflow and elsewhere (e.g. [Rails 3: Sending Mail with Attachment - corrupted file after first send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667565/rails-3-sending-mail-with-attachment-corrupted-file-after-first-send) and [Rails 3.0.7 ActionMailer attachment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105561/rails-3-0-7-actionmailer-attachment-issue)), but none of the solutions offered have been able to help. I've tried two different transports (Gmail SMTP and Sendgrid), several file types (png, pdf, etc.), and both inline and normal attachments, but always with the same effect.

Here's the code for the mailer:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

    # A hash of default values for email messages
    default from: "me@mysite.com"

    def welcome_email(user)
        @user = user
        @url = "http://localhost:3000"

        attachments['logo_email.png'] = File.read("public/img/logo_email.png")

        mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Welcome")
    end
end
```

Where I'm calling it in my controller it looks like this (I'm using delayed_job here, but the attachment is corrupted even without it):

```
UserMailer.delay.welcome_email(@user)
```

Comment: this happens to me too.. :S did you solve it?

Comment: @Lichtamberg Unfortunately, no. :( I also haven't been using Rails recently so I haven't gone back to take another look.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently, this is a Windows-only behavior in how the file is (not) read in. You need to specify both the "r" (read only) and "b" (binary) for Ruby in Windows to read it correctly.
http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html

See the following related issue

[Read contents of a local file into a variable in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055339/read-contents-of-a-local-file-into-a-variable-in-rails)

Try the following:

`attachments['logo_email.png'] = File.read("public/img/logo_email.png", mode: "rb")`